# Register RedHat (rhn_register vs subscription-manager)

Tags: redhat, rhn, subscription

Currently, I do a inventory of the register into own account. 
I saw two types of registers: First, in these list.

[image: Here]

And second, in these one:

[image]

When I tried to compare both, some systems are into both but others only are register in one list.

Those systems that register in both list, may be updated. Those systems that register only into one list, couldn't be updated.

I understand that if I use **rhn_register** command, the name of the system, only appears into Register systems, and if I use **subscription-manager** command, the system only appears into a subscriber Inventory.

So, I don't know what can i do for register a system correctly.

I looking for a manuals or examples, but if i follow the steps, the system only appears into one of the list.

I do not know what is missing for register a system correctly.

Comment: rhn_register use old redhat network and the old subscription style, use the second command https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [use subscription-manager](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273). For connecting directly to Red Hat, Red Hat Network Classic has been deprecated and this service will end in July 2017. You're expected to have [switched all systems over to subscription-manager](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-subscription-management) before that time.

This doesn't entirely apply if you need to connect to an older version of Red Hat Satellite. In this case you can continue to use rhn_register to connect to Satellite.